# static_folder not functioning in Flask debug mode and in development

Tags: python, flask

**My file structure:**

```
my_app
   /models
   /views
   /templates
   /other_folders
   /www (where flask resides)
      /templates
         some_files.html
      /static
         /css
           style.css
      /views
      /models
   my_app.py (run the app in console)
   web_my_app.py (run flask app)
```

**In web_my_app.py, here's how my `static_folder` is set:**

```
app = Flask('my_app',
            template_folder='www/templates/',
            static_folder='www/static'
            )

# As a test, let's develop a basic page 
@app.route('/')
def show_index():
    return render_template('main.html', entry="hello")
```

**The  main.html look like this:**

```
{# Main page #}
{% extends "layout.html" %}
 {% block body %}
 <h2>Main Page</h2>
 {{ entry }}
{% endblock %}
```

**The layout.html has the following for stylesheet**

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
```

**Question: Why do I get a 404 on my static page but not on my template?**

The app manages to access the template files just fine and dandy but has no clue where the static pages are.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but where your static pages?

Comment: @zero323 www/static/css/style.css

Comment: Have you tried using '.static' instead of 'static'?

Comment: @zero323 yes I have in my layout.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you will find that the static files are fine and accessible at `http://localhost:5000/www/static/...`.

Flask's development server by default makes static files available with the same URL prefix that you provide in the `static_folder` argument. If you want the URL to be different you have to add the `static_url_path` argument to your Flask constructor. Example:

```
app = Flask('my_app',
        template_folder='www/templates/',
        static_folder='www/static',
        static_url_path='/static'
        )
```

And now you can find your static files at `http://localhost:5000/static/...`